# Are regular expressions (0*1*)* and (0 + 1)* same?

Tags: regex

I was solving exercise problems in my textbook, and I wondered that whether (0*1*)* and (0 + 1)* are same. I think they are same, but I have no idea how to prove it. Are they same regular expressions?

Comment: What about the space in `(0 + 1)*`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, they are not the same:

- `0*1*` matches any number of zeroes (including none) followed by any number of ones (including none). This is then repeated any number of times (including none) via `()*`
- `0 + 1` matches a *mandatory single zero*, then at least one or more spaces, then one more space, then a *mandatory single one*. Again, this is repeated any number of times via `()*` like before.

So, the two match very different things the first one will match input like `000000` or `1111` because it has (essentially) an optional zero or one, so an input that only has a single of these is correct but not according to the second regex. While the second one will match input that has at least two or more spaces between the mandatory `0` and `1` characters but the first regex will reject that, since it does not allow spaces.

Answer (score 0):

No they aren't. The first on will for example match `0011`, but the second one won't.

You can check how they behave in: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `(0+1)*`instead of `(0 + 1)*` (mind the spaces, they are meaningful when dealing with regex).

To answer your question, **no**. They are not the same.

The `+` quantifier means "one or more" (it does not mean "or" like you might think), so the `(0+1)*` regex will match `01` but not `10`, whereas the `(0*1*)*` regex will match both.

Comment: Also, even with `(0+1)*` the regex will not match `0000000` or `1111`  only input like `01` or `00001` or `0010100001` will match, since both are mandatory, while the first regex allows for each character to be missing.